# How to reLoad a form from another form

Tags: c#

I have two forms, Form1 and Form2. I use ShowDialog() on Form2 from Form1. How can I run Form1Load() from Form2? Specifically, I want to refresh Form1 from Form2.

Comment: Better explain why you think you need to call Form1_Load()

Comment: You pass the reference of the instance of Form1 that spawns Form2 in a Private variable. Then call the Form_Load() event of Form1.

Comment: If you're trying to manually re-execute the code from an event, you're better off putting the code in a method, then calling the method from Forms1_Load and then wherever is appropriate for the subsequent calls.

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of Form1 and then use the Refresh method or your Form1_Load method with that instance.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void ShowMessage(string message)
    {
        MessageLabel.Text = message;
    }

    private void ShowForm2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 Form2Copy = new Form2(this);
        Form2Copy.ShowDialog();
    }

}
```

and

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 Form1Copy;

    public Form2(Form1 Parent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form1Copy = Parent;
    }

    public void Button_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {             
        Form1Copy.ShowMessage("Hello from Form2!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Currently this is missing huge amount of info.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean? What more should I add to the answer?

Comment: How about a [mcve] for a start. @JonathonCarroll shows how it's done. Try and learn from that as a better way to answer here, good luck!

Comment: Does that provide enough of an example?

Comment: in form2 i want to run Parent.ShowMessage("Hello from Form2!") in button_click but get folowing error: Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' does not contain a definition for 'ShowMessage' and no extension method 'ShowMessage' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Amin\Desktop\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form2.cs 25 20 WindowsFormsApplication1

Comment: Hmm... Do you have a class level variable for Parent that you use? Also is there a label on your Form1 and the ShowMessage(string message) method in your Form1 code?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make sure you assigning the `Owner` property on Form2 before showing it. This allows you to access the current instance of Form1.

```
class Form1 : Form
{
    public void Method()
    {
       var form2 = new Form2();
       form2.Owner = this;
       form2.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

From Form2 you can this use this.Owner to access the instance of Form1 and call any public methods or access any public properties. (Make sure the load event handler is public)

```
class Form2 : Form
{
    public void Method()
    {
       this.Owner.form1_Load(null,null); //assuming you don't use these params.
    }
}
```

In your form1_Load() I would recommend putting in a `this.Refresh()` to "refresh" the form. The refresh doesn't update some things that have data stored, it only repaints the form, so in the load event you will have to manually "refresh" things.

Comment: I did exactly as you said. but still geting the folowing error: Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' does not contain a definition for 'Form1_Load' and no extension method 'Form1_Load' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Amin\Desktop\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form2.cs 27 24 WindowsFormsApplication1

Comment: Show us your code that doesn't work @bita_naz simply [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

Pass in Form1 to the ShowDialog() method of your Form2 instance:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.LoadEventCode();
    }

    public void LoadEventCode()
    {
        this.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.ShowDialog(this); // <-- pass in Form1
    }
```

Now over in Form2, cast the .Owner property to Form1 and do what you need:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 f1 = (Form1)this.Owner;
        f1.LoadEventCode();
    }
```